# How can one express the point to set distance by vector component?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

Suppose I have a vector $x = (x_1, x_2) \in \mathcal{X} := \mathbb{R} \times [0,1]$ and a set $\mathcal{A} := \{x \in \mathcal{X} : x_1 = 0\}$, I would like to give the expression of the point to set distance $$|x|_{\mathcal{A}} = \inf_{y \in \mathcal{A}} |x - y|$$ using the components of $x$ formally. Namely, if one is given $x^* = (x_1^*, x_2^*) \in \mathcal{X}$, I would like to arrive at the following expression

$$
|x^*|_{\mathcal{A}} = \sqrt{(x_1^*)^2}
$$

However, I'm unsure how to show this formally. Here is my go at it:

\begin{align}
|x^*|_{\mathcal{A}} & = \inf_{y \in \mathcal{A}} |x^* - y| \\
& = \inf |(x_1^*,x_2^*) - (0, [0,1]) | \\
& = \inf |\big ( (x_1^* - 0) , (x_2^* - [0,1]) \big ) | \\
& = |(x_1^*, 0)| \\
& = \sqrt{(x_1^*)^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Derivation looks OK.  Why the asterix?

Comment: I merely did it for clarity. I agree that it is not necessary, however.